# Why does my SQL query return a record that doesn't match the where clause?

Tags: sql

This query returns a result of one record where both the `[E-mail]` and `[E-mail 2]` are equal to `'e'`. Most definitely the result of a lazy salesman. Any idea why this is the case though?

My query is as shown below so I should only get records where the email is equal to `'emailfromsomeone@hotmail.com'` correct?

```
declare @email as varchar
set @email = 'emailfromsomeone@hotmail.com'

select
    C.[No_],
    C.[First Name] firstname, 
    C.[Surname] lastname, 
    C.[E-Mail] as email, 
    C.[E-Mail 2] as email_2, 
    C.[GDPR Opt-in] as GDPR_opt_in,
    C.[Salesperson Code] as sales_person    
from 
    [Contact] as C
where  
    lower(C.[E-Mail]) = lower(@email)
    or lower(C.[E-Mail 2]) = lower(@email)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared `@email` to be a `VARCHAR`, meaning a *single* `VARCHAR`. When you're setting the `@email` variable, it's being truncated to just the first character.

Try changing `VARCHAR` to something like `VARCHAR(100)`.

Comment: thanks, must be a little early in the morning for me still.

Answer (score -1):

I got it. So i declared the variable like so and then it worked

```
declare @email VARCHAR(255)
```

sorry for bothering you stakoverflow!